# Linker Errors using directX and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, directx

So I've been working on this for the better part of two hours and although I appear to be following the exact instructions of every forum/guide on the internet, I'm still getting linker errors trying to use directX with Visual Studio 2010.

Here is the code I'm starting with:

```
#include <D3DX10.h>  
#include <iostream>   
using namespace std;

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, D3DXVECTOR3& v){  
      os << "(" << v.x << ", " << v.y << ", " << v.z << ")\n";     
      return os; 
}

int main (){  
    return 0;  
}
```

I have the SDK downloaded and installed and I have the manually set up the appropriate include and library directories in the project configuration properties.  I have also set up additional linker input dependencies:

d3dx10.lib
d3dx10d.lib

However, I am still getting the following errors upon compiling:

1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol *WinMain@16 referenced in function _*_tmainCRTStartup

1>C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DX Practice\Debug\DX Practice.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Any and all help is appreciated.

EDIT: Changed int main() to int WinMain().  New errors:

1>c:\users\ben\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\dx practice\dx practice\main.cpp(10): warning C4007: 'WinMain' : must be '__stdcall'

1>c:\users\ben\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\dx practice\dx practice\main.cpp(10): error C2731: 'WinMain' : function cannot be overloaded

1>          c:\users\ben\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\dx practice\dx practice\main.cpp(10) : see declaration of 'WinMain'

EDIT2: Figured it out -

```
int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
```

Thanks all for the help :)

Comment: I never said that `WinMain` was defined the way `main` is.

Comment: Why do you need to use `WinMain` in first place? Just keep it `main`. Change the linker setting: Linker->System->SubSystem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you use a special setting in Visual Studio, windowed executables start with the `WinMain` function, not the regular `main` function. So you should either be creating a console app, be using `WinMain`, or use the setting to use the regular `main` function.

Note that starting with `WinMain` is not required for actually creating windows. It's just a Visual Studio convention.

The option to use regular `main` is under "Linker->Advanced" in the Project Settings dialog. It is called, "Entry Point", and to use the regular main, you use "mainCRTStartup" as the value.

---

If you insist on using `WinMain`, then you need to define it correctly:

```
int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE   hInstance,          // Instance
                   HINSTANCE    hPrevInstance,      // Previous Instance
                   LPSTR        lpCmdLine,          // Command Line Parameters
                   int          nCmdShow)           // Window Show State
```

Comment: What is the standard convention for this?  Should I change the options to use the regular main, or use WinMain?

Comment: @Slims: It's up to you; it's your code. If you like WinMain, use it. If you don't, just ensure that you use the regular one with the project settings. Personally, I haven't used WinMain in quite some time, but that's just my preference. That being said, WinMain does offer some useful data (the previous instance and the Window Show State) which could be useful depending on your application.

Comment: Noted.  Thank you very much for all of your help!

Comment: when changed to "int WINAPI WinMain", it gives an error: C2731: 'WinMain': function cannot be overloaded

Answer (score 1):

If you include the Windows headers, then the linker expects you to provide a `WinMain` function, not the regular `main`. The WinMain entry point provides Windows-specific data like `HINSTANCE`s.

Comment: Not true. A console application may also include Windows headers.